# How to get SOAP Method in JAX-WS CXF Handler

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, cxf

I'm writing a handler, implementing:

```
SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext>
```

I only want to do something on a certain SOAP call, but it looks like the handler gets attached to the web service overall, rather than a specific method.

So, how to check what method is being called in my handleMessage code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK looks like I found a way, not sure if it's the best method but it should work:

```
SOAPMessage message = smc.getMessage();
SOAPBody body = message.getSOAPBody();

//Then grabbing the first child node of the body and checking its name:
Iterator<Node> nodes = body.getChildElements();
// get the first one
if (n.getNodeName().equals("The node name for the particular operation")) {
 // then we have it
}
```